# RUN go build main.go in dockerfile

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to run `go build hello.go` inside a dockerfile, as

```
FROM golang

COPY hello.go /go/src/hello.go

RUN cd src/

RUN go build hello.go

RUN ./hello
```

It all goes well until the `go build` command, then it the following error message appears:

```
stat hello.go: no such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c go build hello.go' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

However, if I comment the last two commands on the dockerfile and run the created image, I can run the `go build` command with no problems.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every RUN command starts a new shell with a clean environment and a new default working directory.  In particular, `RUN cd ...` as an isolated step does nothing.

If you do actually need to change directories in a Dockerfile, either combine the two steps into one or use a [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) directive to make the change more globally.

In the specific case of a Go repository, since there's a [standard directory layout](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Organization) that's at least very strongly encouraged, I'd run with it:

```sh
FROM golang
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/me/myprogram
COPY . ./
RUN go install .
CMD ["/go/bin/myprogram"]
```

(In general Go deals with whole directories or "packages" of related files, and not necessarily individual `.go` files.)